# AngularJS/TypeScript: Failed to instantiate module due to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have a service:

```
module app {
    export interface ISomeService {
        doSomething(): string;
    }

    export class SomeService implements ISomeService {
        doSomething() {
            return "haaay.";
        };
    }

    angular.module('app').service('someService', SomeService);
}
```

I have a controller:

```
module app {
    export interface ISomeController {
        doControllerThings(): string;
    }

    export class SomeController implements ISomeController {
        static $inject = ['someService'];
        constructor(private someService: ISomeService) { }
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').controller('someController', SomeController);
}
```

I also have a routing file (using ui-router):

```
module app {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', 'someService'];
function config($stateProvider, someService) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('someState', {
        url: '/Home/Hello/',
        parent: 'home',
        resolve: {
            someValues() { return someService.doSomething(); }
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                    templateUrl:  /path/to/file/something.html',
                    controller: 'someController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have been receiving this error and I am not sure why:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: someService
```

I know my routing file is basically using plain javascript at the moment, so I apologize for the big eyesore it becomes after looking at a few TypeScript examples.

EDIT: Made a few updates. Bad copy/paste edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7k2IMY3nhTECRXhl97ez?p=preview)

The point is - we **cannot** ask for **`'someService'`** to be injected into **`.config()`** phase. In this case, only **Providers** could be injected and configured.

So, we need to move the dependency for a service directly to **`resolver`** - `someValues : ['someService', (someService) =>` ... // that is the place to ask for 'someService'. Because this will be called in a **`.run()`** phase

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider' ];
function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('someState', {
        url: '/Home/Hello/',
        parent: 'home',
        resolve: {          
            someValues : ['someService', (someService) =>
                                        { return  someService.doSomething(); }]
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                    templateUrl:  'path/to/file/something.html',
                    controller: 'someController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7k2IMY3nhTECRXhl97ez?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. I am going to mark this as the correct answer - after applying the changes, everything works!

Comment: Great to see that, sir ;) Enjoy that mighty combination - Typescript, angular  - UI-Router ;)